# how to align an element inside of your header without taking it out of its form field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my language selector to be in my header (right now doing this with viewport height / width), but when you resize your browser (for example you rescale it to 100% instead of 150%) it starts moving very ugly. I want to prevent this from happening, so I want my language selector to be in my header and scale with the browser normally, but without taking it out of my form field. How can such thing be achieved?

the html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
<select name="language" class="languageSelector form-control required" id="languageSelector"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

how the CSS looks:

```
.languageSelector {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40vw;
    bottom: 9vh;
}
```

how it looks on scale 75%:

[image]

how it looks on 100%:

[image]

I am trying to prevent such thing from happening (see the select field) and to place it visual side inside my header, but NOT to remove it from my form field.

My header looks like this:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 id="exerciseTitleCMS" class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-6">Content Managment System</h2>
    </div>
</div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->
```

Comment: please provide the rest of your html code and CSS code around the header

Comment: use position:relative for language button and absolute for header div

Comment: Add it to the same row as your heading and use the col classes to correspond with your heading so that they add up to 12

Comment: _“My header looks like this:”_, _“HTML how the header looks like:”_ - huh? Are you giving two different codes for what should be the same thing here, or what? Extremely hard to reproduce what your actual problem is, with just these code snippets - please create a proper [mcve]. I am first of all wondering why this element does not actually seem to be part of your header in the HTML structure to begin with? Why is your header not _one_ row with _two_ columns inside it, when that would actually come closest to what you want …?

Comment: It makes very little sense to have that language selector field inside a row/column conbination in the first place, if you then rip it out of there using absolute positioning. That don’t mix well with the bootstrap grid, at least not if you don’t modify the position for each breakpoint as well.

Comment: @CBroe my bad. Thought I didnt put that piece in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML5, you can put form elements anywhere you want on the page, and then use the attribute **`form="..."`** to attach them to the `<form>` that they belong to.

Example:

```
<input form="yourForm" name="..." type="..." />
<select form="yourForm" name="..."></select>

<form id="yourForm" action="..." method="...">
  <!-- other form fields -->
</form>
```